# Porting RDPY to Python3 - AttribueError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I decided to take over a project on my own to fix some issues that the original author seems to have abandoned. The effort is to port the code to Python3 and to update libraries accordingly.

Below is a block of code that I can't seem to figure out.

I've tried StringsIO and BytesIO and neither seem to work.

```
class Stream(BytesIO):
    """
    @summary:  Stream use to read all types
    """

    def dataLen(self):
        """
        @return: not yet read length
        """
        return self.len - self.pos

    def readLen(self):
        """
        @summary: compute already read size
        @return: read size of stream
        """
        return self.pos

    def readType(self, value):
        """
        @summary:  call specific read on type object
                    or iterate over tuple elements
                    rollback read if error occurred during read value
        @param value: (tuple | Type) object
        """
        # read each tuple
        if isinstance(value, tuple) or isinstance(value, list):
            for element in value:
                try:
                    self.readType(element)
                except Exception as e:
                    # rollback already readed elements
                    for tmpElement in value:
                        if tmpElement == element:
                            break
                        self.pos -= sizeof(tmpElement)
                    raise e
            return

        # optional value not present
        if self.dataLen() == 0 and value._optional:
            return

        value.read(self)

    def readNextType(self, t):
        """
        @summary: read next type but didn't consume it
        @param t: Type element
        """
        self.readType(t)
        self.pos -= sizeof(t)

    def writeType(self, value):
        """
        @summary:  Call specific write on type object
                    or iterate over tuple element
        @param value: (tuple | Type)
        """
        # write each element of tuple
        if isinstance(value, tuple) or isinstance(value, list):
            for element in value:
                self.writeType(element)
            return
        value.write(self)
```

The error:

```
[*] DEBUG:  Build size map
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/rdpy-rdphoneypot.py", line 197, in <module>
    size = readSize(arg)
  File "/usr/local/bin/rdpy-rdphoneypot.py", line 154, in readSize
    e = r.nextEvent()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/rdpy/core/rss.py", line 303, in nextEvent
    if self._s.dataLen() == 0:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/rdpy/core/type.py", line 914, in dataLen
    return self.len - self.pos
AttributeError: 'Stream' object has no attribute 'len'
```

All of the code is located here: https://github.com/hackdefendr/rdpy.git

Any pointers to why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear. There's no such thing as `self.len` on a `BytesIO` or `StringIO` object. There was on Python 2's `StringIO` objects, but it wasn't in the documentation. There's also no such thing as `self.pos`, which will be a bigger problem for you, because that code assumes you can not only read from it but also write to it.

You can get much of the same functionality out of the `seek()` and `tell()` functions. `tell()` is equivalent to getting the value of `pos`, and `seek()` is equivalent to setting the value of `pos`, plus you can use `seek()` to get the length:

```
from io import StringIO
s = StringIO('test')

s.seek(2)              # seek to absolute position (pos = 2)
s.seek(4, 1)           # seek to relative position (pos += 4)

current_pos = s.tell()
length = s.seek(0, 2)  # seeks to end and returns the position
s.seek(current_pos)    # returns to previous position
```

Comment: I'm still learning Python so some of this isn't as obvious to me yet. I do, however, understand what you wrote and will see if I can figure out how to use seek and tell. Thank-you for the tip.